# MySQL Function db.GROUP_CONCACT(..) does not exist

Tags: mysql, function

I have a query returning multiple values associated with one thing. For example, if I have a student, and I have multiple test scores associated with that student, I want to list all of this in one row. To do this I found the function Groupd_concact. I am trying to use it as I found it in the documentation: [MySQL 5.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

However, when I try to use it, I get the error message saying:

```
FUNCTION db.GROUP_CONCACT does not exist
```

If it was returning an error saying something else, I would have thought it was just a syntax error, but it seems like it isn't from the error message. If you could please help me out, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry for dumb questions...Would be proper SO etiquette to delete this question?

Comment: It's not a dumb question. Everyone's had at least one occasion where they stare at some code and swear that it's 100% correct, and then turns out they have a simple typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `GROUP_CONCAT`. You've got an extra `C`.

Answer (score 2):

it should be GROUP_CONCAT and not GROUP_CONCACT